# Is it possible to resize a generic object pool?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, arm

I'm working with a real-time application on an ARM device. Performance is important, so I use a generic ObjectPool class.

Up to now I would pre-allocate the pool to the maximum size I could anticipate, but now I am coming across scenarios where I absolutely must resize the pool.

Having looked at a number of solutions around the web and SO, I noticed that the resizing is always an Array-copying operation which triggers the GC. I figured this is ok, but now starting to see performance hits that do matter.

Are there true resizable object pooling solutions/patterns that generate zero garbage?

Comment: If you absolutely must have zero garbage, a linked list or tree of ObjectPool instances might work.  You might lose any real-time guarantees, though.  (Finding an instance can become a linear- or logarithmic-time operation, at least.)  "Resizing" an array just creates a new one (requiring that the old one eventually be collected), and a typical pool will at its core just be an array of instance references...so you'll want to create a new pool rather than resizing an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would code an object pool that uses a linked list internally. This would allow your pool to grow as large as need be. And the pool should add and remove from the start of that linked list. That in turn would guarantee that the very same objects would be re-used when pressure being low.

On the other hand, is constructing and/or tearing down these objects expensive? Because one reason for using a pool in the first place is to manage objects that are expensive to create and destroy.

Another key reason for using a pool is re-use of objects where you pretty much always get the very first objects from the pool with the hope of these objects being available in cpu cache. The fact that you run out of objects in the pool suggests that you do not benefit much from having the pool.

So my recommendation is before you start coding on a new object pool, maybe you should try dropping the pool and see how that impacts performance when you just let the GC do its magic.

Comment: Curious what you did. Used linked list or did you drop the pool?